# jQuery on "enter key" create content editabledom element and select it

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "p[contenteditable]" ).on( "keypress", function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode;
        if(code == 13) { //Enter key
            $(this).after('<p class="new" [contenteditable]>hi</p>');
            $('p.new').css("color","red").focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tehtrav/T2U9M/

I'm trying to create a new `<p contenteditable></p>` when the enter key is pressed and change focus to it, but the focus doesn't seem to trigger. It works if I set the focus to an element other than the new paragraph (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tehtrav/T2U9M/)), but not if I call focus on the newly created paragraph.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want this to work multiple times, or just on the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your code but take the brackets our of the creation of the new paragraph, it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "p[contenteditable]" ).on( "keypress", function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode;
        if(code == 13) { //Enter key
            $(this).after('<p class="new" contenteditable>hi</p>');
            $('p.new').css("color","red").focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. THANK YOU!